# How to define n-bit signed int in systemverilog?

Tags: verilog

We can define unsigned integer like these:

```
typedef bit[4:0] int5; // 5 bits unsigned integer
typedef bit[3:0] int4; // 4 bits unsigned integer
```

How to define type for signed integer?

e.g. 6 bits signed integer range from -32 to +31

```
typedef bit[5:0] signed int6signed; // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the `signed` keyword in the wrong spot. It should be

```
typedef bit signed [5:0] int6signed;
```